# python lists , need find a string and later slice that string get the attached value to it

Tags: python, list

```
description=""" am id: asdm12
             store : 231
             mob  : 00000000"""


if any("am id:" in line for line in dataList ):
    amid_list= line.split(":")
    newAccMap['AMID'] = amid_list[1]
    popup(newAccMap['AMID'])
    print "AM ID:",amid_list[1]

else:
    print " NO AMID"
    popup("No AMID")
```

so this is my code: I want "AM ID:" value , I have used description.splitlines() function and stored it in list . Now in that list I need to search for " AM ID:" if it is present I need get value connected to that colon . else print no am id .

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: Why are you storing those values in a string instead of a dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`for/else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) loop:

```
for line in description.splitlines():
    key, val = line.split(":")
    if key.strip() == "am id":
        print(val.strip())
        break
else:
    print("no am id")
```

Here, the `else` part is executed only if the loop terminated normally, i.e. without hitting the `break`.